# Use json attribute as Foreign Key and format it to uuid

Tags: json, foreign-keys, sequelize.js

I need to list all of the posts inside my application following by the author's name of each.

**Model POST**

```
var post= sequelize.define("post", {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        primaryKey: true
    },

    type: DataTypes.STRING,

    data: DataTypes.JSONB    

}, {
    tableName: 'document',
    paranoid: true
});
```

**Model USER**

```
var user= sequelize.define("user", {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        primaryKey: true
    },

    type: DataTypes.STRING,

    data: DataTypes.JSONB    

}, {
    tableName: 'document',
    paranoid: true
});
```

Note: both of them are inside the table 'document'

One example of each record

**POST**

```
id: 97aabb70-5fef-11e6-8a8c-f783538c5572
type: 'post'
data: { 
    "author": "cd418bf0-5ff5-11e6-be58-bb65628b456c" 
    "message": 'Hello World!'
}
```

**USER**

```
id: cd418bf0-5ff5-11e6-be58-bb65628b456c
data: {
    "name": "foo"
}
```

So, what I need to do is use findAndCount on Posts and retrieve their Author(User) too.

The foreign key would be the attribute "author" inside of the column "data"

**Attempt**

```
post.hasOne(user, {
    foreignKey: "author"
}

options.include = {all: true};
post.findAndCount(options)   //ERROR here
```

**Error received**

```
column user.author does not exist
```

**SQL statement created by sequelize**

```
SELECT count("post"."id") AS "count" 
FROM "document" AS "post" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "document" AS "user" ON "post"."id" = "user"."author"
```

**Ideal SQL statement sequelize should create**

```
SELECT count("post"."id") AS "count" 
FROM "document" AS "post" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "document" AS "user" ON "post"."id" = ("user"."data"#>>'{author}')::uuid
```

*Note: the author's ID inside Post.data is stored as TEXT so I need to cast it to uuid to work properly*

I've tried a lot of ways for this to work, like

```
foreignKey: '\"data\".\'{author}\''
foreignKey: '\"data\".\'{author}\'::uuid'
```

But none of them work for me.

How can I accomplish that ?

Comment: The foreignkey is the column name in the second table. Did you make sure that the `author` column exists inside of the `user` table?

Comment: Well ... I only have 1 table ("document"). It has a JSONB column called "data". My "post" record has an attribute "author" inside of the data's json column.

Comment: What database are you using? MySQL, MariaDB, Postgres, something else?

Comment: i'm using postgres

Comment: You should move the User and Post models into separate tables rather then share a single table. That way relational databases can work better and make it easier for you to query your results.

Comment: it is not possible ... my database doesnt have foreignkeys, it has only one table by design ... unfortunately it seems that it is not possible to accomplish what I want ... I opened a issue at sequelize project on git for that https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6718